# Cast fails when reading from Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to access a value I've stored inside of `Info.plist` and the second line `root = NSDictionary...` fails.

I can however do this to open my other file, `Common.plist`.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist"),
   let root = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
```

Why am I having issues opening `Info.plist`?

Answer (score 4):

`Info.plist` is not `[String:String]`. It can include any property list compliant type.

But there is a pretty convenient shortcut

```
let root = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
```

which returns `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your Info.plist file are not only String:String values, but also String:Number, etc. so String:AnyObject should work.

Comment: Don't use `AnyObject` anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `Info.plist`.  There are all kinds of things stored in there - not just `String`.  If you change to `let root = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any]` you will start passing that check.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch like this:

```
func fetchData(){

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourPlistName", ofType: "plist") {

            if let dicObj = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any] {

            }
        }
    }
```